# Web User Control Postback Issue with Treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, code-behind

I am trying to build a website that has a custom File Explorer.  Eventually I hope to build it out further and allow uploads, but I'm facing an issue calling it from the code behind.

My user control contains a Treeview, and if call it like this:

```
<fe:FileExplorer filePath="/Resources/" runat="server"></fe:FileExplorer>
```

everything works fine, but when I call it from the code behind like this:

```
FileExplorer uc = (FileExplorer)LoadControl("~/Controls/FileExplorer.ascx");
uc.filePath = "/Uploads/Newsletter/";
PAGECONTROLS.Controls.Add(uc);
```

I have an issue with the Post back.

The issue appears to be when I'm getting the selected node.  It grabs the selected node when I use the .Net inline, but when I use the code behind it seems to loose the post back:

```
TreeNode nd = FolderTree.SelectedNode; <-- Always Null when called in code behind.
```

Below is the Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Troop_101.Controls
{
    public partial class FileExplorer : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public string FilePath;

        public string filePath{
            set { FilePath = value; }
            get { return FilePath; }

        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string RootFilePath = Server.MapPath(FilePath);
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(RootFilePath);
                TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode(rootDir.Name, rootDir.FullName);
                FolderTree.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
                TraverseTree(rootDir, rootNode);
                FolderTree.CollapseAll();
            }

            string ReturnStr = "";
            TreeNode nd = FolderTree.SelectedNode;
            if (nd != null)
            {
                ReturnStr = getFolderContent(nd.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                ReturnStr = getFolderContent(RootFilePath);
            }
            RESOURCE_FolderContent.InnerHtml = ReturnStr;

            foreach (TreeNode tn in FolderTree.Nodes)
            {
                tn.Expand();
            }

        }
        private void TraverseTree(DirectoryInfo currentDir, TreeNode currentNode)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in currentDir.GetDirectories())
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dir.Name, dir.FullName);
                currentNode.ChildNodes.Add(node);
                TraverseTree(dir, node);
            }
        }

        private string getFolderContent(string filePath)
        {
            string ReplacePath = Server.MapPath(FilePath);

            var info = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
            var fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            string LinkTemplate = "<table><tr><td><a href=\"{0}\"><img src=\"{1}\" height=\"25px\"></a></td><td style=\"vertical-align:center;\"><a href=\"{0}\">{2}</a></td></tr></table>";

            string ReturnFiles = "";

            if (fileInfo.Length <= 0)
            {
                ReturnFiles = "No Files In Folder<br />";
            }
            foreach (FileInfo file in fileInfo)
            {
                string FileExt = file.Extension.ToLower().Replace(".", "");
                if (!File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images/ExtensionIcons/" + FileExt + ".png")))
                    FileExt = "_blank";


                string fir = filePath.Replace(ReplacePath, "");

                ReturnFiles += String.Format(LinkTemplate, FilePath + fir + "/" + file.Name, "/images/ExtensionIcons/" + FileExt + ".png", file.Name);
            }
            return ReturnFiles;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the .NET

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FileExplorer.ascx.cs" Inherits="Troop_101.Controls.FileExplorer" %>

<div style="width:90%; border:thick solid #656565;margin:0 auto; background-color:#ffffff; padding:5px;" class="tableroundcorners">
    <style type="text/css">
        .node_left {
            padding:5px;
        }
    </style>
    <table style="width:100%;height:350px;">
        <tr>
        <td id="RESOURCE_FileTree" runat="server" style="width:150px;border-right:solid #757575 thin;overflow:auto;">

            <asp:TreeView ID="FolderTree" runat="server" NodeIndent="15" ShowLines="True" LineImagesFolder="~/Controls/FileExplorerTree">
                <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#6666AA" />
                <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" Width="100%" CssClass="node_left" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="0px" NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
                <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="true" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" BackColor="#cccccc" />
            </asp:TreeView>

        </td>
        <td id="RESOURCE_FolderContent" runat="server" style="text-align:left;overflow:auto;">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code behind make sure that your are adding the control in the OnInit method to ensure that the control exists prior to processing the post back data (before the page load event)

http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC386473.png (ASP.NET LifeCycle)